# Frozen Column in Divs Table

Tags: html, css

I have a table generated by DIVs.  I need to have a first cell will be frozen while other cells can move back and forth.

Problem: After position: fixed assigned to the first cell, a second cell is underneath of the first cell.

How to fix this issue so that every single cell will be displayed one after another and the first cell will be frozen and won't overlap the second cell?

Please give a hand.  Thanks

P.S. Because this table is generated by the system, so that we cannot convert it to `<tr> <td> table`.

[Live sample is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ckfdubsf/509/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">
  This cell will be fixed position
  </div>
  <div class="test1">
  111111111111111111111111111111111111
  </div>
    <div class="test1">
  a4a1ece5-070e-6f08-fead-49851ceb7d93
  </div>
    <div class="test1">
  a4a1ece5-070e-6f08-fead-49851ceb7d93
  </div>
    <div class="test1">
  a4a1ece5-070e-6f08-fead-49851ceb7d93
  </div>
    <div class="test1">
  a4a1ece5-070e-6f08-fead-49851ceb7d93
  </div>
    <div class="test1">
  a4a1ece5-070e-6f08-fead-49851ceb7d93
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.test1 {
      word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
}
.test {
  position: fixed;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    width: 120px;
}
html {
  width: 5000px
}
.container {
 /*  display: flex; */
  border: 1px solid yellow
}
```

Comment: Can you alter the html structure at all? Adding a container div around the `.test1` divs and setting it scroll could work

Comment: @ Mituw16, sorry, I can't alter the html because it is generated by the system.

Comment: would something like this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/ckfdubsf/522/

Comment: @Mituw16, Yes it works well.  Thank you.  How to vote for your answer?

Comment: Added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, update your css to the following.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ckfdubsf/522/)

```
.test1 {
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
-webkit-hyphens: none;
-moz-hyphens: none;
hyphens: none;
border: 1px solid red;
width: 120px;
float: left;    
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
margin-left: 120px;
}

.test {  
position: fixed;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
-webkit-hyphens: none;
-moz-hyphens: none;
hyphens: none;
background: green;
color: white;
width: 120px;    
}

html {
width: 5000px
}

.container {
display: flex; 
border: 1px solid yellow;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
position: relative;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this class to your code

```
.container .test1{
  margin-left:120px;
}

.container > .test1 ~ .test1 {
  margin-left:0;
}
```

It gets the first apperence of the class .test1 and add a margin to it.